# How to show self.report of operator called from another operator?

Tags: python, add-on, operator

When I call an existing operator in the execute function of another operator I have created, the self.report from the existing operator is not triggered. Is there a way to enable this, or access the reports of the existing operator somehow so they can be called by my operator?

Answer (score 2):

##### Test success version: v2.92, v2.93

##### Test failed version: v3.3 (I hope someone can explain that)

1. Run script and call the operator from search menu : xx
2. Make sure you have an object selected and the report is: Deleted 1 object(s)

```
import bpy

import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

stdout = io.StringIO()

def catch_report(fn): # not catch error
    with redirect_stdout(stdout):
        fn()

    stdout.seek(0)
    return stdout.read()


class XX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "xx.operator"
    bl_label = "XX"

    def execute(self, context):
        def fn():
            bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)

        tx = catch_report(fn)
        if tx:
            tx = tx[:-1]
            print(tx)
            self.report({'INFO'}, tx)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(XX)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(XX)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. This is how I tried it: 1)Add Cube to scene 2)Paste code into text editor and run 3)Select Cube and delete using xx operator from search menu. There's no report. If I delete the cube normally there is a report.

Comment: Are you a Mac user? I tested on window11, it works on blender 2.92.

Comment: Windows 10, Blender 3.3.

Comment: I tested v3.3 the `catch_report` function doesn't work and the operator cannot register on the search menu. Some api seems to have changed on v3.3